# Questions on homothetical equilateral triangles

Tags: geometry

[image]

I have been given this image, ABC = equilateral.
In triangle ABC, AD is the median.
BD=CD=1 and $AD=\sqrt{3}.$

AEF = equilateral, with sides $2 \cdot \sqrt{3}$
Line AD intersects EF in G. Z is the centroid of AEF. The line through C and Z intersects AE in K.

Now I have got 3 following questions which I can't seem to figure out at all.

> a) Triangle CDZ and HGZ are similar.
>
> b)  The length of DZ is $2-\sqrt{3}$
>
> c) Prove that EH is as long as AB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part is true as $\angle CDZ = 90^{\circ} = \angle ZGH$ and also $\angle CZD = \angle GZH$

For the second part note that the length of the median line in an equilateral triangle is given by $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}a$. Therefore we have that $AG = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \cdot 2\sqrt{3} = 3$. Now the centroid divides the median in ratio $2:1$, so therfore we have that $AZ = 2$. Finally:

$$DZ = AZ - AD = 2 - \sqrt{3}$$

For the final part we have using the first and second part that:

$$\frac{GH}{GZ} = \frac{CD}{DZ} \implies GH = \frac1{DZ} = \frac1{2 - \sqrt{3}} = 2 + \sqrt{3}$$

Now $EH = GH - GE = 2 + \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{3} = 2 = AB$